# What is the Stack Exchange policy for removing closed questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, etiquette

What's the Stack Exchange policy for deleting closed questions from their websites?

At least 1000 questions get closed every day. I am aware that deleted questions are kept at a separate website for deleted questions.

I just wish to know under what circumstances closed question would get removed.

Comment: _"100 questions get closed everyday"_, this isn't experts-exchange... try multiplying it by 10 and you might be closer.

Comment: Deleted question stay where they are, still visible with enough rep (10k+), they're not moved elsewhere (unless someone grabs them).

Comment: _"I am aware that deleted questions are kept at a separate website for deleted questions."_  And where is that, exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions are deleted when they:

1. are not currently adding value to the site; typically in the form of a good answer that was posted before the question was closed.
2. cannot be improved to be on topic; the question is unsalvagable. That, or the question is unlikely to ever be salvaged (the author was given ample opportunity to improve the post and it has been long enough that they are clearly not going to).

There are both automated and manual processes for this. When a Q/A [meets certain criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/186381) that indicates it is both not useful and unlikely to be improved, it's deleted.

Questions can also be deleted by a moderator at any time, or by 3 10k+ community members (if the post is at least 2 days old or has a score less than -3 by 20k+), if they feel that the above criteria apply.

Comment: Don't forget those nasty 10K-ers that can delete questions that are 48 hours on hold/closed....

Comment: I always mix up whether 10k allows deleting questions or answers; edited.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're talking about auto-deletion, and not deletion from human intervention:

> The system will automatically delete closed (not as a duplicate), unlocked questions with zero or negative score having no upvoted or accepted answers or pending reopen votes, that were closed 9 or more days ago and haven't been edited in the past 9 days.

There are many more criteria for automatic deletion for non-closed questions, as well as certain rules for human intervention. These can all be found at [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/262755)

Comment: See also [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) about automatic deletion.